# Anchors within the Same page are not working properly

Tags: html, laravel

I'm trying to link to elements within the HTML of my page, but it's not working and I don't know why.

I don't seem to find any error in this.I am just unsure why it's not working. It just shows the name of the link i.e. f1, f2 or f3 in the URL but won't link to that particular section. It actually should not show the anchors in the URL, but not sure what is wrong.

I'd like all the links's in this list to be links to three ids:

Links:

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
First:

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active"> <a href="#f1" data-toggle="tab"> Personal Details </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#f2" data-toggle="tab">  Official Description </a> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#f3" data-toggle="tab"> Official Details </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="progress-indicator"><span></span></div>

<div class="tab-pane with-bg active step1" id="f1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="deputationDiv" class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Full name</span> 
                    <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_name}}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Date of Birth</span> 
                    <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_dob}}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Email-id</span> 
                    <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_email}}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    Second:

    <div class="tab-pane with-bg step2" id="f2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Employee code</span> 
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_employeecode}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Employee type</span>
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_type}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Batch Year</span> 
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_year}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      Third:

      <div class="tab-pane with-bg step3" id="f3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <div class="panel-title">
                    Present PLace
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">City</span> 
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_workcity}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Location</span> 
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_loc}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Oh yes it is, But it's working in chrome and Microsoft edge?

Comment: route and controllers?... Wait, just adding.

Comment: There is also a space in `data- toggle`

Comment: I checked it, that's not causing problem @mplungjan . Actually there wasn't space in the code, it just appeard here. sorry for that.

Comment: It's not working in the snippet either @mplungjan

Comment: First of all, what you're trying to implement? A  tab structure or a page scroll? if you need a page scroll, remove the attributes `data-toggle="tab"` from the `<a href="#f1" data-toggle="tab">...` If you need a tab structure you're missing some more markups which bootstrap is recommending.

Comment: Yes I need tab structure, Please can u tell me which markup am I missing which are needed here? @JTheDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="active"> <a href="#f1" data-toggle="tab"> Personal Details </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#f2" data-toggle="tab">  Official Description </a> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#f3" data-toggle="tab"> Official Details </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane with-bg active step1" id="f1">
    First
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div id="deputationDiv" class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Full name</span> 
                      <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_name}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Date of Birth</span> 
                      <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_dob}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Email-id</span> 
                      <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_email}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane with-bg step2" id="f2">
    Second:
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Employee code</span> 
                        <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_employeecode}}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Employee type</span>
                        <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_type}}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>    
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Batch Year</span> 
                        <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_year}}</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane with-bg step3" id="f3">
    Third:
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <div class="panel-title">
                Present PLace
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">City</span> 
                      <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_workcity}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Location</span> 
                      <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_loc}}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please go through the above code. The markups you were missing is added. Please not the `role="tablist"` and `role="tabpanel"` Those are important to render the proper design.

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion gave it better look, which I was trying to get from a pretty long time, now it looks like tabs. But, Problem which was occurring is still there. it is still not navigating to those pages.

Comment: @Rock: which pages? this is tab system. You can navigate to different tabs. Where is the concept of the page? Please update the path of .css and .js files according to your location. The above was my local path.

Comment: Yes yes, I gave them as per my location and sorry tabs, not pages. But what I am saying is, clicking on the links, is not navigating me to that particular tab.

Comment: Which browser you're using? any script error in the developer console? any not found error in console?

Comment: I am using crome and Microsoft edge. My other projects were working fine but this is not, this is something bothering me.

Comment: localhost:8000/Details/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:8000/Details/css/main.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Rock: I also replicated the error. The problem with me was the order of importing bootstrap.js and jquery.js. jquery.js should load first and then bootstrap.js should load. Then only it'll work. Otherwise the css will load the styles but not the script functionality. There'll be an error in developer console also.

Comment: But, I have these files in my app/public/css folder. It's not loading them I think

Comment: @Rock: Use the correct URL in `<link href...` Without that it'll not work

Comment: http://localhost:8000/Details/js/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/Details/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8000/Details/js/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::to('src/css/main.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
 @include('includes.header')
 <div class="container">
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div>
  @yield('content')
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Rock: You can do one thing, instead of using url(), use asset(); This will refer to resources/assets folder. You can keep your js and css files here. You can even define a directory structure also

Comment: Thank you very much @JTheDev. I'll check the link.

Comment: I removed those errors. Used CDN links. But still, the problem is same.It's still not navigating. Now, there are no errors in the console but the same problem is still there. Have done everything, now what to do? @JTheDev

Comment: I just don't understand. The code is working properly there also. But, isn't working when I try to run it on my browser in my computer. Well, I'll try to figure out something. But' trying from past 2 days, still don't know the solution. The problem is, same code is working fine on my friend's computer, but causing problem in mine. @JTheDev

Comment: make sure that the javascript is enabled in the browser. By default, it is enabled in every browser, but developers might change it for testing purpose. I don't see any problems other than that. check in other browsers also in your system itself.

Comment: Okay, @JTheDev, I'll check that. Thank you.

Comment: I have checked it, and javascript is enabled in my every browser... @JThedev

Answer (score 0):

In this case we don't need routes and controller info, it's just a plain HTML functionality. Your `data-toggle` tags must have a different ID's, for example: `data-toggle="tab1"`,`data-toggle="tab2"` and `data-toggle="tab3"`. Also you can remove this data-toggle tags, you don't need it if you want only links (anchors) to the content.
Please check working code in the Snippet.

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
First:

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active"> <a href="#f1"> Personal Details </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#f2">  Official Description </a> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#f3"> Official Details </a> 
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-pane with-bg active step1" id="f1" data-toggle="tab1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="deputationDiv" class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Full name</span> 
                    <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_name}}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Date of Birth</span> 
                    <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_dob}}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Email-id</span> 
                    <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_email}}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    Second:

    <div class="tab-pane with-bg step2" id="f2" data-toggle="tab2">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Employee code</span> 
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_employeecode}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Employee type</span>
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_type}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Batch Year</span> 
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:left">{{$user->user_year}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      Third:

      <div class="tab-pane with-bg step3" id="f3" data-toggle="tab3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default panel-border " style="background:#fcfcfc">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <div class="panel-title">
                    Present PLace
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">City</span> 
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_workcity}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                          <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:40%; text-align:left">Location</span> 
                          <span class="form-control" style="text-align:right">{{$user->user_loc}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I checked it, But it shows no improvement. Same problem is still there. Can you please suggest something else?... or Are you able to figure out the problem now even after improvement? because I am not.

Comment: Sorry, what you mean? Please check "Run code snippet" button below my post. It's working.

Comment: Oh yes right,  sorry, I tried to update my code and checked in my browsers,  Yes it's working here but isn't working in my browser. what's the problem, I just don't understand. Even same code in running in my friends computer, but not in mine.